# How to show a list of items without a tableview which changes when the input changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

i know that the question sounds weird but i couldn't find a better way to put it or any solution online or with my current knowledge. I currently use a view controller + a table view where user enters a list of elements to filter my database (core data) and when he clicked the search button i fill tableview with filteredContent.

Now the question is this.

how can i show this filtered content simultaneously in the same viewController where user enter the input?

Is it possible? If yes how?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the user enters the filter via text field, make the view controller the text field's delegate and implement shouldChangeCharactersInRange:.

Each time the input changes, apply the search as if the search button was pressed.

But it seems the real question is how to do this without a vc transition.  The answer is either convert to an [NSFetchedResultsController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which does this kind of thing for a living, or do it yourself via the table view datasource methods.

If the latter, you'd keep an array that holds filtered search results.  As the user enters search terms, you search core data, place the results in that array, then reload the table view.  The datasource methods base their answers (numberOfRows, cellForRow, etc) on that array of filtered results.

Comment: yes the user enters via text field but i don't get what you'r offering.Where will my filterdContent will be shown ?

Comment: I guess I'm confused about the question.  It says "when he clicked the search button i fill tableview with filteredContent".  Is that tableview in a different vc?

Comment: haha yeah. That's main part of the question :) as i explained i m taking input from a view controller and when search clicked i show content in a different view controller ( tableviewcontroller)

Comment: I see.  Okay, edited with my best shot.  Sorry for misunderstanding.